# Place to ask questions about hosting an Ubuntu 14.04 release party?

Tags: discussion

My company is interested in hosting an Ubuntu 14.04 release party.  Googling really has not revealed any solid info on how to go about doing that (save for the list of LoCos hosting them [here](http://loco.ubuntu.com/events/global/2702/)).

Is this type of question appropriate for the main Ubuntu site?  Or would Meta or another site be a better fit?

Comment: If you can word it properly it would probably be fine, if indeed there is a definitive answer. It might be better off on discourse.ubuntu.com or the ubuntu forums though.

Comment: I can answer this, use the [tag:locoteams] tag

Comment: Though I seem to have covered this before: http://askubuntu.com/questions/23264/how-do-i-organize-an-ubuntu-party-or-get-together

Comment: Perfect!  Thank you Jorge.